# How to call AWS lambda function in my PHP code to send emails

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have created a PHP script which uses PHP Mailer and Twilio API to send emails and SMS messages to some clients. Now when I run that script it takes very long to send even to only one client.

Is it possible to create an AWS lambda function and pass the parameters ('to', 'from', etc.) from my PHP code to that lambda function, and then that function will run in the background to send emails and SMS messages?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [mcve] and [ask] and then improve your question using the edit link below your question.

Comment: You first need to create a lambda function which will send email. Lambda function does not support PHP runtime out of the box so you can choose to write Lambda code in Python, NodeJs, Java or C#. Then you need to sue AWS CLI for PHP to invoke the Lambda function from PHP. Documentation of Lambda Commands is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Lambda.LambdaClient.html)

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. I just checked aws documentation and now aws supports php runtime for lambda functions. here is a link .
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/aws-lambda-custom-runtime-for-php-a-practical-example/

Answer (score 0):

Lambda function won't send emails for you, but it will start the process. Here is a solution I developed last week:

[AWS Email Sending Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrTX5.png)

You post email messages on the queue, then a Lambda function is triggered, the lambda uses aws-sdk to send the email with AWS SES.